# javascript caller is being removed what's the alternative?

Tags: javascript

As announced here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller

> Avoid using it, and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.

What's the alternative to do this kind of reflection ?

Comment: Basically saying : NO alternatives.

Comment: A well-designed function should be *passed* the information it needs (either as argument or `this`-"argument").

Comment: I don't think there is one, that's a code smell anyway. A function shouldn't need to know anything about its caller.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery not if you want to do code generation

Comment: It might be that you'll be able to find workarounds for each use on a case by case basis. Do you have an example?

Comment: @user310291 There is no direct alternative. If you have an actual problem that you want to solve without `.caller`, tell us more about your use case.

Answer (score 1):

### The caller should pass any information required to the callback

The consensus on features like caller are that they are a code smell. You need to pass additional information, if the callback function needs to know something about its context.

```js
function doStuff() {
    console.log("caller is" + doStuff.caller);
}


function doStuffWithoutCaller(context) {
    console.log("additional context is: " + context);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="doStuff()">
Caller
</button>

<button onclick="doStuffWithoutCaller('buttonClick')">
Without caller
</button>
```

In reality it is very unlikely that browser vendors will pull the rug out from under you.